# What is the meaning of "orientation" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I came across this word at the beginning of a section of my math book.what is the meaning of **orientation** here?
[image]

Comment: Big blocks of pasted text images are a pain.  You can include them for context, but please type in text the actual words you are asking about.

Comment: "preparation for a new job or activity" - Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: Not only are pictures of text a nuisance for sighted users, they cannot be read at all by non-sighted users using reader software & cannot be indexed by search engines… making them truly useless as a resource.

Comment: In this case, my opinion was that a large part of the text should be displayed so that the audience will understand that this phrase is given at the beginning of a section of the book. In addition, this text can be easily read and zoomed, and the desired word is written in bold. I assumed that all readers are sighted and have the ability to see content.

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect. Not all humans can read pictures. No search engine can read pictures. Your question becomes an unsearchable resource to the entire world & also illegible to non-sighted people.

Answer (score 3):

Metaphorically it means "pointing you in the right direction by giving you a map".

When you join an organisation, you may go through an "orientation" process, in which you are told how the organisation works, so that you can work effectively in the organisation.

Here you are being given an orientation as an introduction to the chapter. You are told the structure of the section. It gives you a "map" so you know what to expect.

This is a creative use of the word "orientation". I don't recall seeing it in this context before. But from the context, I think the meaning is clear.